# How do I load a keras saved model with custom Optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, keras-2

I have compiled and trained a keras model with a custom optimizer. I saved the model but when I try to load the model, it throws an error stating `ValueError: Unknown optimizer: MyOptimizer`. I tried to pass MyOptimizer as a custom object something like : `models.load_model('myModel.h5', custom_objects={'optimizer':MyOptimizer})` and it still throws an error. How do I load the model a keras model with custom Objects?

Comment: To save/load state of a custom optimizer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same problem :)

I made it work by loading the model with `models.load_model('myModel.h5', compile=False)`.

From the keras [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/saving.py#L513):

> If an optimizer was found as part of the saved model, the model is already compiled. Otherwise, the model is uncompiled and a warning will be displayed. When `compile` is set to False, the compilation is omitted without any warning.

After the uncompiled model is loaded, I can compile it again with my custom optimizer.

Comment: btw, you don't need to compile for inference only

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the name of optimizer class as the key in the custom_objects dictionary, in your case, as the optimizer would be 'MyOptimizer' object,

```
models.load_model('myModel.h5', custom_objects={'MyOptimizer': MyOptimizer})
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. However, I had two different custom things in my model. One was my optimizer and the other was a custom layer. Therefore, I solved my problem as follow:

```
my_loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_models_name.h5', custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer , 'AdamWeightDecay': optimizer})
```