# Can't load Keras model using RectifiedAdam optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

Trying to load a Keras model using `tf.keras.models.load_model` I get the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import RectifiedAdam
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model', custom_objects = {'RectifiedAdam' : RectifiedAdam})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 99, in load
    training_config))
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saving_utils.py", line 229, in compile_args_from_training_config
    optimizer_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizers.py", line 819, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='optimizer')
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 292, in deserialize_keras_object
    config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
  File "/mylib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 250, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown optimizer: RectifiedAdam
```

I can load the model with compile to False `tf.keras.models.load_model('model', compile=False)` and then compile it again with RectifiedAdam optimizer (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565801) - however that is not ideal...

So any ideas on, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

One quick hack around this is to manually assign `RectifiedAdam` to an object in the Tensorflow namespace:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import RectifiedAdam

tf.keras.optimizers.RectifiedAdam = RectifiedAdam
...
```

Answer (score 1):

or do something like this:

```
models.load_model('myModel.h5', custom_objects={'MyOptimizer': MyOptimizer})
```

Answer (score 0):

The model was trained on a tensorflow (Keras) version higher than the one you want to use to load the trained model. Find the compatible version of TensorFlow (Keras).