# Does load_model load optimizer state?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I load model via `keras.models.load_model` that was saved via `model.save`

Then I'm trying to print optimizer state:

```
from keras import backend as K
tf_session = K.get_session()
print(model.optimizer.iterations.eval(session=tf_session))
print(model.optimizer.lr.eval(session=tf_session))
```

Which prints:

```
<tf.Variable 'Adadelta/iterations:0' shape=() dtype=int64_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Adadelta/lr:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
0
1.0
```

Or onother way to obtain optimizer parameters:

```
print(model.optimizer.get_config())
{'lr': 1.0, 'rho': 0.95, 'decay': 0.0, 'epsilon': 1e-07}
```

So my question is does keras reset optimizer state on model load?

According to this
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/saving.py#L473
it should save model's optimizer's state.

And here is an actual code that save optimizer state:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/613aeff37a721450d94906df1a3f3cc51e2299d4/keras/engine/saving.py#L132

Optimizer config:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/613aeff37a721450d94906df1a3f3cc51e2299d4/keras/engine/saving.py#L146

Optimizer weights:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/613aeff37a721450d94906df1a3f3cc51e2299d4/keras/engine/saving.py#L157

**UPDATE:**

What does `model.optimizer.weights` contain?

```
keras.__version__ 2.1.6

print('len(model.get_weights())', len(model.get_weights()))
w1 = model.get_weights()[0]
print('type(w1)', type(w1))
print('w1.shape', w1.shape)

len(model.get_weights()) 86
type(w1) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
w1.shape (3, 3, 3, 16)

print('len(model.optimizer.get_weights())', len(model.optimizer.get_weights()))
w2 = model.optimizer.get_weights()[0]
print('type(w2)', type(w2))
print('w2.shape', w2.shape)

len(model.optimizer.get_weights()) 116
type(w2) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
w2.shape (3, 3, 3, 16)

print('max abs diff w1-w2', np.max(np.abs(w1-w2)))
max abs diff w1-w2 0.8932746
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should save the state. The states are not reset when loading.

The correct way to check this is using the `model.optimizer.weights` list:

```
model = load_model(....)
loaded_optimizer_states = [K.eval(w) for w in model.optimizer.weights]

#resetting the optimizer
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', ...)
reset_optimizer_states = [K.eval(w) for w in model.optimizer.weights]

for w1,w2 in zip(loaded_optimizer_states,reset_optimizer_states):
    print('equal?', (w1==w2).all())
```

Now, it doesn't necessarily save everything we want. The `lr`, for instance is not usually a weight, but just a config. There will be an internal calculation for the actual `lr` using the `iterations` value.

But you can also see in the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py), in the `get_updates` method of the optimizers, that:

- `SGD` saves the iterations as a weight: `self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments`
- But `Adadelta` doesn't: `self.weights = accumulators + delta_accumulators`

So, although the weights should be saved, you're looking at the wrong variables, and `Adadelta` seems to have a buggy code. If you use `decay` with `Adadelta`, you should probably manually save and load `iterations` or create a custom copy of the optimizers code where you add `iterations` to the `weights` changing the line above with:

```
self.weights = [self.iterations] + accumulators + delta_accumulators
```

Looking at the codes, it seems `SGD` is the only one that actually saves `iterations`, which seems to be a general bug in saving/loading optimizer states.

Opened this issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13027

#### What are `model.optimizer.weights`?

They are two different things:

- `model.weights`: the weights of the model, they make the model work correctly even if you don't have an optimizer (it's possible to use models without compiling if you just want to make predictions)
- `model.optimizer.weights`: the state of the `optimizer`. They are not necessarily related to the model's weights, they just define how the optimizer should "update" the model's weights when training.

**Now, what is each of the weights in the list?**

That depends a lot on which optimizer you are using. You can see the source code to understand what each optimizer saves as states.

The `SGD` optimizer has `self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments`. This means that the state of the SGD saves the current iteration (which is used to define the current `lr` when there is a decay ) and the `moments` of the optimizer.

The `moments` are a list containing tensors with the same shapes as the list of `model.get_weights()`. Because there is a momentum for each of the models weights.

Other optimizers use more complex mathematical calculations and can have more things as optimizer weights. The `Adadelta` for instance, has `accumulators` and `delta_accumulators`. I don't know what they are, we should study the mathematical formulation of this optimizer. But it's something in the same line of the `SGD`: optimizer states that will define how the model's weights are updated during training. They probably have also the same shapes as the model's weights, but twice.

Comment: What are `self.weights` (`model.optimizer.weights`) actually, i.e. what they contain and how it's related to `model.weights`? see my update.

Comment: See answer. These vars aren't really meant for regular users to understand. Only if you want to do very tricky things or custom optimizers you should understand them fully.

Comment: Seems here is a version of manually saving and loading optimizer state using `model.optimizer.set_weights`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504376/1179925

Comment: The state is saved and loaded automatically. There is only the problem with `iterations`. You should save and load `iterations` manually, the rest is ok. Use `K.set_value(model.optimizer.iterations, loaded_value)` after loading. **Do not compile a model after loading, this will reset the optimizer**.