# Can any Keras objects be subclassed / serialized? Models, apparently no, how about Optimizers?

Tags: python, serialization, keras

I'm working with Keras, as bundled with Tensorflow 2.1.  I am trying many different model architectures.  I have learned that Keras `Model` objects are difficult, if not impossible, to serialize using Python's `pickle`.  Using `JSON`, of course, is out of the question.

Writing a `Model` object to disk using `pickle.dump()` does not fail.  However, when you attempt to reload it, you've lost your model weights.  I'm not sure why.  To get around the problem, I've built a Python wrapper class for Keras Models which can reconstruct the model from data which can be serialized.  I have to recompile the Model and set its weights once it has been reloaded from disk, but that's not a huge obstacle.

Now, I now want to do the same thing for an `Optimizer` that I've done for my models.  I've already determined that JSON rejects Optimizers, and pickle accepts them.  But I also know from working with Model objects that unpickling may not work.

I have a possibly-related problem with Tensorflow `Dataset` objects.  I can create a subclass of `Dataset`, but I can only add attributes and NEW methods.  I was unable to override an existing Dataset method (I wanted to modify `Dataset.padded_batch()`).

Before I waste time attempting to apply Pythonic approaches to Keras (Tensorflow) objects: does anyone know which of these objects can be serialized and/or subclassed?  Is there a guide somewhere?  For now, I only really need to know about Optimizers, but in the future I suppose I might try to save or subclass another object.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save and load model optimizer state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state)

Comment: That's definitely related -- but a bit puzzling.  I checked the version of Keras that is bundled with my Tensorflow, it's Keras v2.2.4-tf.  According to the comment you posted, Keras 2.2.4 is supposed to allow Model pickling, but I did not succeed.  Maybe the last time I tried this was before I upgraded Tensorflow?  I will investigate further.  I have workarounds, but they are kludgy and I would like to write idiomatic, streamlined code.

Comment: From the Tensorflow Keras [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model), `model.save` saves the optimizer state as well. But it does state that `v1.x` optimizers can't be saved as they are not compatible, you might want to check if that describes your case.

Comment: Thanks for your continued replies.  It looks as if `model.save` might finally do what I want.  I am pretty sure that I haven't chosen `v1.x` optimizers, but I will check.  I'm currently trying SGD with the Nesterov option, and Adam.  I assume that Keras would have updated these standard and common optimizers to keep pace with other upgrades.  The main issue is that I want to document the hyperparameters, but resuming training is something I may eventually explore.