# ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on optimizer RMSprop with a weight list of length 3, but the optimizer was expecting 0 weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a saved model in 'h5' format. I am trying to resume training and trying to load the weights of the optimizer after compiling the model using

`model.optimizer.set_weights(weights_list)`

where `weights_list` is a list of numpy arrays containing the optimizer weights that I manually extracted from the h5 file.

But I am getting the above error.

When I try `model.optimizer.get_weights()` I am getting an empty list.

I want to know how to initialize the optimizer weights without any error.

However, if I do

`model = tf.keras.model.load_model('~/modelname.h5',custom_objects={},compile=True)`

It works, that is I can resume training with the previously saved weights.

However, `tf.keras.models.load_model` doesn't always work and sometimes it requires one to build the model and use `load_weights` to initialize the model.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself. Running `model._make_train_function()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state) fixed the issue for me.

```
x = Input((50,))
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(x, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.load_weights('weights.h5')
model._make_train_function()
with open('optimizer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    weight_values = pickle.load(f)
model.optimizer.set_weights(weight_values)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying these lines of code but I get this error : AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_make_train_function', why this?