# How to save optimizer in Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, save, load

I am not using model.compile() function, and I am following ['Writing a training loop from scratch'](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch) (Therefore, simple 'model.save()' does not include my optimizer). Also, I create NN using a functional API in Tensorflow. So, I am able to save using 'model.save()', but it saves only NN model and does not save the state of my optimizer.

I think I was able to save an optimizer using pickle, but somehow I am no longer able to save it before

(it give me an error message (AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'make_gradient_clipnorm_fn..'))

I can use 'get_config' and 'from_config' methods, but it does not save weights. There is another solution to save weights like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089235/6813564). I am looking for a better (and simple) solution.

(and actually this method does not work for me because I am not only training 'model.trainable_weights', but also other 'tf.Variable', which are not belong to my 'model'.)

Is there any easy and convenient way to save and load optimizer?

Thanks

colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jn2lbMcaVURpKITL6qEQ-05XndVDoABQ?usp=sharing

or
--code--

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import os
import importlib
import pickle
import time
from pathlib import Path

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(gpus)

"""Generate samples for training"""

my_dtype = 'float32'
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx(my_dtype)

num_smpl = 500

amp1 = 0.5

x = 0.5*np.random.rand(num_smpl, 1).astype(np.float32)
y = amp1 * np.heaviside(x, 0) - amp1*0.2*np.heaviside(x-0.15, 0) \
    + amp1*0.2*np.heaviside(x-0.17, 0)

mu, sigma = 0, 0.001 # mean and standard deviation
white_noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_smpl).reshape(-1, 1)
y = y + white_noise


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=5, edgecolors='k')

"""Create model using a funtional API"""

layer_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=my_dtype)
layer_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh', dtype=my_dtype)(layer_input)
layer_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh', dtype=my_dtype)(layer_dense)
layer_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='', dtype=my_dtype)(layer_dense)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=layer_input, outputs=layer_output, name='my_model')
model.summary()


epoch = 1
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, epsilon=1e-09)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

"""Training using a custom training loop"""

while epoch < 100:
    with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
        output = model(x, training=True)
        mse = loss_fn(output, y)
    grads = t1.gradient(mse, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print('Epoch: {}, Loss: {}'.format(epoch, mse))

    epoch = epoch + 1

"""Normal variables can be saved using pickle"""

print('Cur. locaiton: ' + os.getcwd())
a = np.arange(0., 10.)
print(a)

with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as file:
  pickle.dump(a, file)

"""***How to save optimizer?***"""

with open('my_opti.pkl', 'wb') as file:
  pickle.dump(optimizer, file)
```

'

Comment: please show your code

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state/49504376 help ?