# get TensorFlow model details from checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need to extract details from saved checkpoint (index & data files)
info like:

- which optimizer algorithm
- which learning rate
  ... etc.

how to get this details from python TensorFlow or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if all the information you want has been saved in the checkpoints you are referring to (some of them have to be explicitly asked to be stored, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503748/save-and-load-model-optimizer-state)).

In any case the [TF documentation about checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint) is quite well done.

You can extract information by

```py
reader = tf.train.load_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts/')
shape_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
dtype_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_dtype_map()

sorted(shape_from_key.keys())
```

and get the dictionaries keys to look at, *e.g.*

```py
key = 'optimizer/learning_rate/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE'

print("Shape:", shape_from_key[key])
print("Dtype:", dtype_from_key[key].name)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but this didn't get which optimizer algorithm
result is 
Shape: []
Dtype: float32